# Remove hidden text and formatting in MS word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

A encrypted text is inserting to my word document 2010,

by default word is treating the text as hidden text and its marked as red color.

I got to know how to display that hidden text but, can any one tell how to remove formatting by default

So, my word should not recognize hidden text & its format also, how to make it as default text

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. Please [edit] your question to include more details about the document, are you the originator or not, what you've already tried and an example or screenshot of what you are dealing with.

Comment: @Shadow, I think maybe what you are trying to say is you have tracked changes enabled. Please read up here and see if this info helps: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/word-help/remove-tracked-changes-and-comments-from-a-document-HA001219021.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Clear all text formatting`?

You can easily clear all formatting (such as bold, underline, italics, color, superscript, subscript, and more) from your text and return your text to its default formatting styles.

1.Select the text that has formatting you want to clear.

2.On the Home tab, in the Font group, click Clear All Formatting Clear Formatting   [image].

Note   In OneNote, this button will be on the Home tab, in the Basic Text group.

That is based on MS Word Help